# In AS3 how would you delete all the properties that have been set on an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Does anyone know how I could remove properties that have been set on a static object in AS3?

Ideally it would be something like -

```
foreach(property in GlobalStaticVar.properties) {
    GlobalStaticVar.removeProperty(property);
}
```

Does anyone have any hints where to look.

Sorry I am a bit of a flash noob.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that, however, is there any reason you don't want to assign it a brand new instance of the object itself? Like a standard object can be cleared using `obj = {}` or if it's a custom class instance you can use `obj = new SomeClass()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var p:String in GlobalStaticVar) {
    delete GlobalStaticVar[p];
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is not the proper syntax in AS3. Make sure you include the space: `for each`